# unset array item if it has certain word in it Php

Tags: php, arrays

Trying to unset an array items. which include "list" word in it. I tried some ways, but didn't managed it. I must doing something wrong in my code I guess...

Array is:

```
[0]=>
  string(41) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/kansai/"
  [1]=>
  string(43) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/hokkaido/"
  [2]=>
  string(41) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/tohoku/"
  [3]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/sp/list.html?area=areaKansai"
  [4]=>
  string(64) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/sp/list.html?area=areaHokkaido"
  [5]=>
  string(62) "http://www.sumitomo-rd-mansion.jp/sp/list.html?area=areaTohoku"
```

Try to delete items which include "list" word and so I tried this.

```
    $needle = "list";

    if (($index = array_search($needle, $allArea)) !== false) {
        unset($allArea[$index]);
    }
```

But still it returns all items... How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-search.php) is comparing each string entry with `$needle` like

```
$url == $needle
```

This means you'll never get a match unless the entry is literally "needle". Even if it does match, it only returns the **first** entry found.

You may find a [filter](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) operation more successful

```
$needle = 'list';
$filteredAreas = array_filter($allArea, function($url) use($needle) {
    return strpos($url, $needle) === false; // filters out URLs containing $needle
});
```

Comment: this approach solved the problem. also thank you for the explanation too.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing about this. How can I push unsetted items to another array? is it possible in this function? Thank you

Comment: @Barbie you could try the difference between the filtered array and your original: `$removed = array_diff($items, $filtered)`.